# Related Category Issue

Tags: categories

I have this code. All seems fine but the categories info won't output between my H4 tags. Not sure what I am missing here but I think it has something to do with the 'related categories mode' parameter. Any help would be appreciated.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="work" limit="20" status="New|Open" related_categories_mode="yes" custom_fields="yes"}
        {if no_results}
            <p class="alert">There are no related projects.</p>
        {/if}
        <li>
            <a href="{title_permalink="work/view"}" title="{title}"><img src="{project_th}" alt="{title}" />{if status == "New"}<img src="/_/img/new-work.png" class="new" alt="NEW Project - {title}" />{/if}</a>
            <h3><a href="{title_permalink="work/view"}" title="">{title}</a></h3>
            <h4>{categories backspace="2"}<a href="{path="work"}" title="">{category_name}</a> / {/categories}</h4>
            <p>{project_excerpt}</p>
        </li>
        {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the User Guide [1](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#related-categories-mode):

> "Relationships, Reverse Relationships, Pagination, and Categories are
>   not available when Related Category Mode is enabled."

Answer (score 0):

It's quite yucky and requires *a lot* of parsing, but you may be able to do this by nesting an embedded template with a second channel entries loop inside the first:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel='work' 
    limit='20' 
    status='New|Open' 
    related_categories_mode='yes' 
    disable='pagination|member_data|custom_fields'
}
    {if no_results}
        <p class="alert">There are no related projects.</p>
    {/if}

    {embed='work/related_entries' entry_id='{entry_id}'}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

And the embedded template (`work/related_entries`):

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel='work' 
    entry_id='{embed:entry_id}'
    status='New|Open' 
    disable='pagination|member_data'
}
    <li>
        <a href="{title_permalink='work/view'}" title="{title}">
            <img src="{project_th}" alt="{title}" />
            {if status == "New"}
                <img src="/_/img/new-work.png" class="new" alt="NEW Project - {title}" />
            {/if}
        </a>
        <h3><a href="{title_permalink='work/view'}" title="">{title}</a></h3>
        <h4>{categories backspace='2'}<a href="{path='work'}" title="">{category_name}</a> / {/categories}</h4>
        <p>{project_excerpt}</p>
    </li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The key here is the `entry_id` variable which is passed from the first channel entries loop to the second.

I haven't tested this, but I think it should work.

Comment: Many thanks I will give it a whirl and come back to you.